# Looping through columns to run regression

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am trying to run a macro that loops through different columns, to run regressions with different variables against one constant column, column H. But I don't know how to phrase it in the recorded part of the macro, the regression bit, so that it loops through. Any thoughts on how to incorporate the for loop so that I can have 1 constant column and one column that changes?

Thank you!

```
Sub RunRegressions()
'
' RunRegressions Macro
'

'

    Dim lastcol As Long, i As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        lastcol = .Cells(3, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        For i = 12 To lastcol

             Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Regress", ActiveSheet.Range("$H$3:$H$134"), _
                 ActiveSheet.Range(i & "3" : i & "134"), False, False, , "", False, False, _
                 False, True, , False

        Next i
    End With



End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the line

`ActiveSheet.Range(i & "3" : i & "134")`

to

`.Range(.Cells(3, i), .Cells(134, i))`

You can also drop any other references to `ActiveSheet` within your `With` block to reduce redundancy.

Comment: The code is running now, thank you! But now it works for the first time it loops, but then I just keep getting a notice that says there isn't any data in the column until it exits the loop even though there is data in the columns. Any thoughts on why that might be happening?